# limit problem about polynomials

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I don't understand why the limit of the polynomial is incorrect.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}a_1x^n+a_2x^{n-1}+...=\lim_{x\to\infty}a_1x^n(1+\frac{a_2}{a_1}x^{-1}+...)=\lim_{x\to\infty}a_1x^n\cdot\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{a_2}{a_1}x^{-1}+...)=\lim_{x\to\infty}a_1x^n$$
I originally thought this was right until it failed under some circumstances.  I think it is the $\infty$ that makes the statement false.  Please tell me which step is illegal and why is it illegal.

$a_1\ne0$ and polynomial of degree n

Comment: Can you give an example where it fails? (There's a problem if $a_1=0$, but that has nothing to do with limits.)

Comment: Where did it fail?

Comment: Consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}1=\lim_{x\to\infty}(a_1x^n-a_1x^n+1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(a_1x^n+1)-\lim_{x\to\infty}a_1x^n$.
If that holds, it would equal zero, would'nt it?

Comment: @BarryCipra $a_1 \neq 0$ for a polynomial of degree $n$.

Comment: Your example in the comment is different than the original question. In the comment, you are taking a difference between infinities, which is indeterminate. However in the question you split a limit into two pieces, one which is infinite and another that is non zero constant, which works just fine.

Comment: @Dragonemperor42, where does it say the polynomial is of degree $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you did in the question body is ok. The problem from the comments is here:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}1=\color{red}{\lim_{x\to\infty}(a_1x^n-a_1x^n+1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(a_1x^n+1)-\lim_{x\to\infty}a_1x^n}$$

we can't use the limit addition rule to split into terms whose limits are not finite. ($\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form).

Comment: Is it still wrong when I say $0=\lim_{x\to\infty}x-\lim_{x\to\infty}x$?

Comment: @user615345, Yes. $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} x-\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x=\infty-\infty$ which is indeterminate.

Comment: Correct me if I go wrong. It is illegal to split into an indeterminate form, and is illegal to combine an indeterminate form.

Comment: @user615345, Yes, that's it. Splitting and combing are the reverse of each other. So if one is illegal, the other is as well.